# How to make time go slow in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a VR project on Oculus with Unity, and I want to make the time in-game go slow. Now I use the code below:

```
Time.timeScale = 0.1f;

Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02F * Time.timeScale;
```

Fortunately, it goes quite well, but when I play it, the picture becomes wierd. You can see everything in the scene twice or a third time. I checked on the internet and it says this codes makes the whole game process slow, including rendering.

So does anybody know how to make the effect which looks like bullet time and meanwhile doesn't make the background process slow?

Comment: [just leaving this here as a tip](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/08/bullet-time-effect-unity3d.html) as for next time include some more details, where are you calling this? also, unity and unity3d are 2 totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

The example in [`unity3d docs for Time.timeScale`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) is misleading: you shouldn't modify `Time.fixedDeltaTime` unless you need to. Just stick with the first line and you should be fine.

`Time.fixedDeltaTime` sets how often physics gets updated. You might want to tweak it, but if you're not using rigidbodies, then you have no need to (are you?).

Comment: Ok. I'll try your advice later. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In my opinion @ycyipman is doing it right, because if fixedDeltaTime isn't adjusted physic objects won't move smooth. But sure you are right, if there are no rigidbodies, then there is no need to adjust it BUT it also has no negative effect if there are no physic objects. So a generalized solution would consider adjusting both values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video to a speedtutor video. It shows you how to make your game run in slow motion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkEtAfL6aoc